# How to visualize divergence correctly?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, divergence-operator

I have posted two figures. 1st is for `$F=xi+ yj$` and 2nd is for `$F=yi+ xj$`
[image]

[image]

For the first $div F=2$ and for second $div F=0$.

I have the idea that if the bigger vectors come out of the circle, the divergence is positive and if the same size and number of vectors go in as out of the circle then divergence is zero.

But here no such differences are shown. For both cases, it seems to me that bigger vectors come out of the circle. But divergence is zero for the second figure. What to do? How to visualize correctly?

Edit: Please give me a proper visualization technique of divergence from the plot of vector field...

Comment: For what "comes out of the circle" you need to take into account what is parallel to the normal vector at the circle and ignore what is parallel to the tangent. Doing it properly will inevitably lead you to Gauss' theorem.

Comment: There seems to be a slight difference. In the second case you can see that longer arrows point out of the 0 to 3 o'clock section of the circle, but vectors point into the circle all along 4 to 11 o'clock. They might be smaller, but add up to more over the whole thing. In contrast the first picture shows that the vectors point out of the circle for a larger sector of the circle than they point in, AND the vectors pointing out are larger, so you'd expect positive divergence.

Comment: Not very clear to me. Please give me a proper visualization technique of divergence from the plot of vector field...

Comment: Are you confusing divergence with flux?

Comment: Divergence quantifies the extent of fluid movement away from specific locations, whereas flux measures the overall outward flow of fluid from a given region.

Comment: Outward parallel to the normal vector. To me it seems that this was the missing piece in your visualization.

Comment: @KurtG. Would you kindly elaborate so that I could understand...please ..

Comment: It is quite unclear what approach works best in your case. From Martin Frenzel you demanded a "proper visualization technique". Whatever that is. Perhaps [this](https://books.physics.oregonstate.edu/GSF/visdivcurl.html) ?

Comment: The site I linked to has also some [interactive stuff](https://books.physics.oregonstate.edu/GSF/divggb.html) into which you can plug in your two vector fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the flux through the circle you have to take the projection  of the vector field ($\boldsymbol{\color{blue}{blue}}$) to the outward normal vectors at the circle (***black***). This gives you the $\boldsymbol{\color{red}{red}}$ vectors. In the case of
$$
\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}
$$
which has divergence two we see clearly that there is net flux out of the circle:

[image]

In the case of
$$
\begin{pmatrix}y\\x\end{pmatrix}
$$
the net flux is zero:

[image]

Comment: Great graphics, but you mean the *projection* of the vector field on the outward normal, not their scalar product.