# The Divergence Theorem - Intuition behind relating divergence with flux

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, vector-analysis, divergence-theorem

I'm currently a 2nd-year math major in college. After finishing Calculus 3 from the Stewart calculus book, I'm left wanting a deeper intuition on all of the vector calculus topics (Green's Theorem, Stokes Theorem, and the Divergence Theorem). Namely the Divergence Theorem. It feels like we simply *"went through the motions"* of learning the theorems, but I would like to gain further intuition into the relationship between flux and the divergence theorem.

Do you ever come back to these topics and gain further intuition on these theorems in higher-level math classes? If so, when? As these topics seem crucial for physics etc...

P.S. If anyone has good recommendations for a good book or a good source to gain some insight on these topics it would be much appreciated!

Thank you for the help!

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4717283/how-to-visualize-divergence-correctly/4717556#4717556) might help.

Comment: Tristan Needham's "Visual Complex Analysis" is helpful, although it only covers the 2D case, not the 3D case. (I imagine his "Visual Differential Geometry and Differential Forms" covers these in more detail / in more dimensions, but I haven't read it yet.)